# query about View.OnClickListener() in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand what is `View.OnClickListener()`.
I have read this site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html, but I cannot understand who is the client and who is the listener.

Please explain in details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is
>   clicked.

[`reference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Simply said: So when you implement this, you are able to *handle click events* for your `Views` - all widgets as `Button`, `ImageView` etc..

When you implement this you have to implement `onClick` method. When you click on some `View`, this method is immediately called.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()) {
      // do your work
   }
}
```

But don't forget that you have to register your `OnClickListener` for specific *widget*

```
someButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Most likely you need to learn **Android basics** and i recommend it to you.

**Note:** You can use Listeners also as anonymous classes

Answer (score 0):

This is an Interface to implement for classes which want to get a notification if a View element got clicked.

For instance:

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onCreate(...) {
        View v = findViewById(...);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // method which is invoked when the specific view was clicked
    }
}
```